# On gaps in the dimension of subspaces

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, polish-spaces

Let $P\subseteq\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$, with $0\in P$. Does there exist a "nice" space $X_P$ such that $X_P$ has a subspace of dimension $n$ iff $n\in P$? By nice I mean nice enough that there's no need to worry about what "dimension" means, ideally a Polish space, but separable metrizable spaces would also work.

I know that surprisingly for $P=\{0,\infty\}$ there is even a compact Polish example, but I'm not sure whether there can be such gaps in the dimension of subspaces for finite dimensional spaces, so an easier question for which I'd also like to know the answer is the following: Let $X$ be a Polish space with $\dim X=n<\infty$. Must $X$ have subspaces of all dimensions between $0$ and $n$?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is such an $\{n,0\}$ example in Polish spaces for every $n$. So of dimension $n$ but a non-empty subspace can only have dimension $n$ or $0$.
See van Mill's book on infinite-dimensional topology (his first) for a proof and references.

Comment: very nice, then taking disjoint unions produces examples of $X_P$ for any $P\subseteq\Bbb N$. Do you happen to have a more precise reference inside the book? I only found a $\{\infty,0\}$ example

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti 4.7.10 or there-abouts. It’s in the part about totally disconnected spaces.

Comment: I see that there is a construction of a totally disconnected topologically complete (which I suppose means Cech-complete) space of dimension $n$, am I missing an obvious reason why it doesn't have subspaces of intermediate dimension, or does it follow by carefully checking the details of the construction?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti the latter IIRC. Check out the original papers for more perhaps.